# How to change the boundary condition near singularity

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

The following system has a singularity around $x=0.451$. What I want to do is to detect when the solution gets close enough to this singular point (in this example I'm using the threshold of $0.001$), negate the value of the solution at this threshold, and use it as the boundary condition for the remaining part of the range.

I tried assigning the location and value of the boundary condition by some variables that later I can change within a `WhenEvent`. It would be a "jump" over the singularity, but my trick doesn't seem to get the job done.

```
bpoint = 2;
bc = 1;

solution1 = 
 NDSolveValue[{f'[x] == Cos[x]/(1 - Sin[Exp[x]]), f[bpoint] == bc, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[1 - Sin[Exp[x]]] < 0.001, bpoint -> x; bc -> -f[x]; 
    "RestartIntegration"]}, f, {x, 0, 2}]
```

Here, I think the problem is that the singular point still exists in the range. So my next try was to change `x` too, linearly, assuming that at this point the slope is equal to that of the threshold. If I use "StopIntegration", integration stops at $x=0.48$

```
solution2 = NDSolveValue[{f'[x] == Cos[x]/(1 - Sin[Exp[x]]), 
   f[bpoint] == bc, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[1 - Sin[Exp[x]]] < 0.001, "StopIntegration"]}, 
  f, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Now if I shift the location to slightly before the singular point, `NDSolve` works:

[image]

But manually using these values in`WhenEvent` still doesn't work:

```
solution3 = 
 NDSolveValue[{f'[x] == Cos[x]/(1 - Sin[Exp[x]]), f[bpoint] == bc, 
   WhenEvent[Abs[1 - Sin[Exp[x]] < 0.001], bpoint -> x - 0.3; 
    bc -> -f[x]; "RestartIntegration"]}, f, {x, 0, 2}]
```

I'm thinking if done properly, the system should not have any problems with the singular point because `NDSolve` can easily solve either side that we have the boundary condition. Any help would be much appreciated.

Maybe the answer lies in understanding how "marching" is done in `NDSolve`?

Comment: Are you sure that a unique continuous solution even exists? To me this is like trying to solve $f'(x)=1/x^2$. Just because for $x<0$ you can find a solution $f(x)=-1/x+c_1$ and for $x>0$ you can find $f(x)=-1/x+c_2$ doesn't mean you can join them up into a single solution.

Comment: @Rahul I'm sure it exists because we can modify the differential equation so that it does, and that's the main question. Even for your example, if we shift the solution by a very small amount, one of them will have the same sign as the other. For me it doesn't matter if one of them is now $(-1/(x-0.0001) +c$ and that's were the threshold comes in. Maybe take a look at this example from documentation: 
`NDSolve[{y'[t] == a[t] y[t], a[0] == 5, y[0] == 1, 
   WhenEvent[y[t] == 10, {y[t] -> -10, a[t] -> -5}]}, {y, a}, {t, 0, 
   1}, DiscreteVariables -> {a}  ];`